# How to set score recalculation after undoMove for some planning entities?

Tags: optaplanner

For some planning entities, even the planning variables are the same, the shadow variables (e.g., the end time of a procedure) can be different. By defaut, the score of a solution after undoMove will not be recalculated.  However, the structure of the solution after undoMove will be different, compared to the structure before move, due to the duration of the procedure is random. This will result the UndoMove Corruption. For these planning entities with random durations, can I recalculated the score after the undoMove. Or how can I fix this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your solution is different after an undo move, that is a score corruption. It must not happen. As far as I know, your problem does not have a solution - undo move must result in a solution that has the same score as before the move was made.

Undo moves are performed very often. The solver tries various random moves, and before it decides to apply one of them, it needs to revert all the others. Therefore it is not possible for your undo moves to alter the solution in any material way.

If you are using a custom move, cache the values you are replacing, and then in the undo move, restore the values to their exact original cached versions.

Comment: Can I cache the whole solution before a move? And restore the cached solution in the undoMove? If this is possible, is there any doc or example I can reference?

Comment: You'd have to clone the solution, which is expensive. And in the end, you'd still have to modify the working solution; you can not replace the working solution with another instance.